# How do I add List of items that is stored in my Java file into My List Activity?

Tags: android

Can anybody please help me in adding List of items that is stored in my Java file into My List Activity. I fetch the list items from remote database through my JDBC connection (java.sql). Then I try to store it in different variables in a java file. Finally I want to fetch these items and display it in my list. How do I do it?
Also I would like the list items to be dynamic as in future new items might be added.

My List item will be an array List.

Thanks & Regards,
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

For the listView part you will need to write an adapter that fetches the data from your java file and bind it to each row in the listView. 
Read [this](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) tutorial for custom list views.

- Salil